# How to add an additional onselect behaviour without override default @bind in blazor select?

Tags: blazor

I have multiple select fields on my component and would like to add a custom `@onchange`-handler (like an `onafterchange` or something like that) in addition to the default `@bind`-behavior (value and `@onchange`).

This handler should only set a flag to indicate that the user can save, because this selection has changed a value of the parameter. For an input field, the `@oninput` can be used for this (see code below).

I don't want to overwrite the default `@onchange` but just add this to it.  Is there a way I can add this or do I have to manually overwrite the `@onchange` for each select field on the component?

I tested `@onselectionchange`, `@onselect` and `@onselectstart` but these sadly weren't called.

```
// MyComponent.razor

<button disabled=@IsDisabled @onclick=DoSave>Save</button>

<input type="text" @bind=TestSample.TestInputValue @oninput=SetChanged />

@* How to call SetChanged after @onselect here? *@
<select @bind=TestSample.TestOptionValue>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
</select>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public TestSample TestSample { get; set; }

    private bool IsDisabled;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
        IsDisabled = true;
    }
    
    private void SetChanged()
    {
        IsDisabled = false;
    }

    private void DoSave()
    {
        // Do some Task...
    }
}
```

```
// TestSample.cs

public class TestSample
{
    public string TestOptionValue { get; set; }
    public string TestInputValue { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options here. One would be to wrap it into an `EditContext` and subscribing to the `FieldChanged` event or what I would suggest in your case is not to use `@bind` and set the value of `TestSample.TestOptionValue` inside the callback handler. In the next step, you set the value to the field/property. In the handler, you do the additional logic and setting the value.

```
<select @oninput=@HandleSelect value="@TestSample2.TestOptionValue">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
</select>

@code {
   private void HandleSelect(ChangeEventArgs args)
   {
        TestSample.TestOptionValue = args.Value as String;
        SetChanged();
   }
}
```

Remember that @bind is to simplify "trivial" operation, where your only interest is to get a value back from an event. What @bind does is nothing else than subscribing to the event and set the value of the property/field to the ones provided in the handler.

So, if you want to do more than this operation, you can "bind" by yourself and do additional logic inside the callback.